# PDF version issue when including PDF figures

Tags: xetex, pdf

I keep getting the following line in my log file

```
** WARNING ** Version of PDF file (1.5) is newer than version limit specification.
```

with reference to each image I'm trying to include in my document. The images are inserted easily enough but I'm just a little miffed about this message. I used Inkscape to create the images, and when I was exporting them to PDF, the only option I had for versioning was 1.4. I'm also using XeTeX to compile the document.

How can I get rid of these messages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this in your preamble for pdftex:

```
\pdfminorversion=4
```

for XeTeX edit the configuration file `dvipdfmx.cfg` which can be found 
for TeXLive in `/texmf/dvipdfmx/` and replace the first line with

```
V 4
```

It also maybe the other way round, then change it from 4 to 5

Comment: This doesn't work with XeTeX.

Comment: @Chris: see my amnswer for XeTeX

Comment: @Herbert don't you mean V 5? Since the version mentioned in the warning is 1.5?

Comment: @Alan: 5 is the default and if I understand the problem described correct than the images want to have 1.4 but the document want to be 1.5. However, otherwise it is vice versa :-)

Comment: @Herbert But if the images are 1.4, and the document is 1.5, that should not produce the warning, since 1.4 is compatible with 1.5.  So it seems that Chris's version of `xdvipdfmx` is assuming version 4 and not version 5.  Maybe an older installation?

Comment: @Alan: pretty easy to solve, a look into the config file or in the pdf file will give the needed information.

Comment: @Herbert, thanks a lot, using V 5 is what worked.

Comment: @Herbert: so, it is just a matter of the xelatex engine not being happy with the version of the included pdf images, or is there really something wrong with including version 1.5 pdf images with xelatex?

Comment: @pluton: it is only a problem with the config setting

Answer (score 13):

If the only images that yield the warning are your Inkscape ones, then the export command wasn't doing what it claimed, since the warning says that the images are 1.5 and not 1.4 (as you thought you had exported them as.)

There is no way to specify the pdf version using xelatex (although there is in pdflatex).  Howver, you can specify the minor version when running the `xdvipdfmx` command.  So the following should get rid of the warnings: (this from the command line).

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -V 5" <yourfile>
```

Depending on what OS/editor you're using you can probably make a new script/engine to do this from within your editor.

Answer (score 8):

You could try lowering the version numbers of the included PDFs with ghostscript's `ps2pdf14`.

`ps2pdf14 input.pdf output.pdf`

Yes, even though it says "ps2pdf14", it works with pdf files as input. (There is also ps2pdf12, ps2pdf13, etc.)

Comment: That's a clever observation that it works with .pdf, too! I've done this in two steps before...