# PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.5>, but at most version <1. 4> allowed

Tags: errors, graphics

How do I get rid of this error:

```
PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.5>, but at most version <1. 4> allowed
```

I tried putting `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=5` after my preamble, but nothing happens.

---

(Edit added by Andrew Stacey):

I've seen this error in the following situation.

1. I created some PDFs using TeXLive2010 with the most recent stable PGF/TikZ (in case it is relevant).
2. I cropped these PDFs using `pdfcrop`, again from TeXLive 2010.
3. I sent these to another person, who included them in their document with the `graphicx` package.
4. That person used TeXLive **2009** to compile the document.

(I'll need a little time to dig out a MWE!  I'll need to figure out how to switch between TL2010 and TL2009 on my machine.)

Comment: Are you including any other PDFs as pictures? Check the PDF version of them. Which version of `pdflatex` are you using?

Comment: I have two pdfs as pictures, how can I find out what version of pdflatex I'm using?

Comment: Both the PDFs are 1.5

Comment: It is in the first line of the `log` file. Also check the PDF version of the resulting PDF.

Comment: Where's the $log$ file? Sorry, I'm new at this :S

Comment: @Carol: The `.log` file is normally in the same directory your `.tex` is in.

Comment: It says Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8)

Comment: (preloaded format=pdflatex 2010.12.25)

Comment: I've been getting this error recently, but I can't remember exactly what circumstances led to it.  If I can track it down, I'll see if I can post an example.

Comment: @Carol: your `pdflatex` version is up-to-date, so its not the problem. (Hint: you should put a `@` followed by the user name you want to address into you comments. This way the user gets a notification. Note that the OP of the question/answer always gets a notification.)

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8821/2693) will help.

Comment: I've tracked down where I've seen this error before and edited it in to the question.

Comment: @Andrew: As indicated in the question linked by @Alan, the default PDF version switched to 1.5 between texlive 2009 and 2010. You can go back to 1.4 in 2010 by `\usepackage{pdf14}` (or just `\pdfminorversion=4`), or you can reset the default by editing the configuration files. Alternatively the person with TL2009 could say `\pdfminorversion=5`.

Comment: I had this error when using `inkscape` to convert `.svg` to `.pdf` and including them in LaTeX (with ubuntu's version of TL09)

Answer (score 5):

Did you try `\pdfminorversion=X` ? At least it works for me...

Comment: Then it says ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: when I have \begin{document} below it

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\pdfminorversion=6
\begin{document}
 Text
\end{document} This is the right syntax and should run.

Comment: now it says 
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

and it doesn't finish and get the PDF to be previewed.

Comment: This is no way to solve your problem. No one can find the mistakes in just tiny bits of code an error messages. You should post a minimal example (see the FAQ) please.

Comment: @Carol: meep.meep is quite right; it would be best if you edit your question and include a minimal example that exhibits the error. That can even be helpful if we don't have the `pdf`s that you want to include.

Comment: Thank you! I used \pdfminorversion=6 right before \begin{document} and it worked perfectly. I am using pdf figures made in Adobe Illustrator CS4 and the error used to come up for every figure but this has taken care of it.