# Beamer: problem with \framezoom and XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, hyperref

I have a problem getting the `\framezoom` command to work when compiling with XeLaTeX, using fully updated MikTeX 2.9.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=zoom]
    \frametitle<1>{Test zoom}
    \framezoom<1><2>[border](1cm,1cm)(3cm,2cm)
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
\end{frame}
\againframe<2->[plain]{zoom}
\end{document}
```

This works fine with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX: there, it creates the two slides as expected, but both the hyperlinks and the border on frame 1 are missing.

I have checked the log-file and the hyperref uses the hxetex driver, i.e. the same as if I pass the option `xetex` to hyperref manually.

Any idea how to fix this? (For some reasons, I need to use XeLaTeX.)

Thanks

PS: I hade to use a PNG version of the picture, as with PDF-version I run into a [pdf-version problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8821%20) and the picture is not shown at all.

Comment: Works here with an up-to-date TeX Live: can you give us your `\listfiles` output?

Comment: @JosephWright I have updated my MikTeX but the problem is still there. The log file after adding `\listfiles` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22320179/se_148487_mwe.log).
In addition, I have just noticed that XeLaTeX output several warnings of type `** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.` to std-err.

Comment: Well that is quite an old release of `beamer` (from 2012), so somewhere something is not up to date. Those warnings also got fixed a while ago: I suspect an 'old version' problem.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for spotting this out - weird that MikTeX ignores this update. I have now updating beamer and checked all installed packages from the last two years (manually), so now it should be up to date.
However, the problem still remains, including the warnings mentioned above. I have updated the [log file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22320179/se_148487_mwe.log).

Comment: @JosephWright, I experienced the same problem, works for pdflatex, but not for the  desired xelatex, I use TexLive2013 distribution and beamer v 3.30, any update on this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because caused by outdated beamer version